# Kapow ManagementConsole could not start

Tags: kofax

An error message pops out when I try to connect to the management console. The version is Kapow 10.1.0 master nightly 2370 x64. 
The Error message is:

> Unable to register to the default cluster: ManagementConsole failed to start: Spring subsystem failed to load.. Retrying

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the folder on Kapow Appdata User Profile folder, for example:

```
C:\users\<user>\appdata\local\Kapow
```

And then restart the RoboServer/Management Console.

This will create a new configuration and from there you can continue the installation (bring up the management console, enter the license, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Please Delete Appdata and open localhost:50080 Management console and delete and then add Cluster settings again.
Now restart the Design studio and open it up again. Make sure you are using same objectdb.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to rename the folder:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Kapow\10.ur.version\Data
```

Then rerun the Management console as Administrator.

If you are still facing the same issue, please uninstall Kapow and install it again (also make sure you renamed the `Data` folder).